# UITableView Spacing/Gap between cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using UITableView with two different custom cells. Both cells have different height. I'm returning the height of both cells programmatically. I set the separator type to NONE.

Problem is that there is 1px gap between two cells. There should not be 1px gap between two cells. I debugged the view using view hierarchy to make sure that gap is between cells or inside cell and i found out that gap is between cells.

Comment: Can you provide some code or a screenshot?

Comment: If you are using storyboard,please provide screenshot. And some codes will be useful

Comment: How about adjusting the top of the second cell's subviews? Try to make the top -1.

Comment: @Xchord cell will cut off inside, instead of overlapping the above. Gap is between the cells.

Comment: @ThihaAung Sure, i'll update my question with code shortly.

Comment: @0yeoj Sure, i'll update my question with code shortly.

Comment: @chaudharyshahbazsaleem probably better to have a code and some screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating xCode to 8.2 and setting headers height to 0.0f worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've set `yourTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.0f;`, if you haven't implemented `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`. Otherwise, if you have, return `0.0` in that delegate function.

As well, if that doesn't work for some reason and you need a quick last-minute fix you can extend your view's frame over the bottom edge by 1px. Though I would not recommend this for a long term solution.

Comment: This is unlikely the issue. The two cells are probably in the same section and by default a section header's height is 0.

Comment: I set the header height to zero but still same issue. I don't know what's wrong with the tableview. I found somewhere that it should be due to some tableview bounds. But he didn't told that what to do with bounds.
Can bounds be an issue?

Comment: Can I ask what's the particular reason you can't work with this 1px gap? I understand it's an annoyance, though if it's a background colour issue for example, can you make it blend? (ie. the 1px line is white, everything else is purple, make the line purple by changing the colours for the table). Otherwise, bounds might be an issue somehow. Can you post code by any chance?